# How to call API URI with my input data

Tags: python, api, url

To do geocoding I tried to get customer information API from pitney bowes for that they given following details.

given :

```
POST https://api.pitneybowes.com/identify/identifyaddress/v1/rest/validatemailingaddress/results.json HTTP/1.1

    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: Bearer {YOUR ACCESS TOKEN}
    Host: api.pitneybowes.com
    {
      "options": {
        "OutputCasing": "M"
      },
      "Input": {
        "Row": [
          {
            "AddressLine1": "",
            "AddressLine2": "",
            "City": "",
            "Country": "",
            "StateProvince": "",
            "PostalCode": "",
            "FirmName": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I'm getting response 405 for my program. why do I get `<Response [405]>` on sending post request?

My program is:

```
import requests
url = 
 'https://api.pitneybowes.com/identify/identifyaddress/v1/rest/validatemailingaddress/results.json HTTP/1.1'
data = '''{
"options": {
    "OutputCasing": "M"
    },
"Input":
    {
    "Row": [
        {
            "AddressLine1": "line1",
            "AddressLine2": "line2",
            "City": "xxx",
            "Country": "yyy",
            "StateProvince": "aaa",
            "PostalCode": "xxx",
            "FirmName": ""
            }
        ]
     }
    }'''
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                              'Authorization': 'Bearer 
{nGdl0cndcnYN0FK6gmeFQ6CXRYO9}'}
response = requests.post( url, data=data,
                     headers=headers)
print response
```

Comment: What language is this? Please [edit] the question and add the relevant tag so the relevant experts can find their way here.

Comment: Why are you sending the data like that? All sorts of things can go wrong with it... Just make your own dict with the same structure and use use `json` argument when providing it to the `requests.post()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The IdentifyAddress API standardizes and validate addresses, you should use [Geocode API](https://locate.pitneybowes.com/geocode) for geocoding.

Here is the correct python code to invoke Identify Address API, hope this helps:

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.pitneybowes.com/identify/identifyaddress/v1/rest/validatemailingaddress/results.json'
data = '''{
"options": {
    "OutputCasing": "M"
    },
"Input":
    {
    "Row": [
        {
            "AddressLine1": "4750 Walnut St",
            "AddressLine2": "",
            "City": "Boulder",
            "Country": "USA",
            "StateProvince": "CO",
            "PostalCode": "80301",
            "FirmName": "Pitney Bowes Software"
            }
        ]
     }
    }'''
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer YImXVIfpDOsadpv8SCohGAC0ALcO'}
response = requests.post( url, data=data, headers=headers)
print response.text
```